# How to make QT Application write a crash log

Tags: c++, windows, qt

i am working on project developed in Qt, Windows,
i use Qt Version 4.1.4 and VC6 IDE for compiling project, most of usage of product are on WindowsXp.

i frequently receive crash reports from testers and customers which does not have fix pattern and does not reproduce in my development environment.

so i come to the conclusion that i need to write a crash log from my program so that i always get the call stack when program is crashed.

in linux i know its possible to do it with some signal handling of segmentation fault. but how to do the same thing in windows/C++?

i tried to search on Google to find some ready made solution but without any luck.

Suggestion regarding any third party tools/libraries (free or licensed) are also accepted, but please do not suggest any method where i have to modify each function in my module to get log, because the project is huge and i can not afford that.

thanks in advance.

updates.
I have attached StackWalker to my Code now (with bit of hassle of _MBCS & UNICODE) but atleast managed to attach it.

my main file looks like below,

```
class MyStackWalker : public StackWalker
{  
   FILE *sgLogFile;
   public:
   MyStackWalker() : StackWalker() 
   {
     sgLogFile = fopen("ThisIsWhatIcallLog.log", "w");
   }
   MyStackWalker(DWORD dwProcessId, HANDLE hProcess) : StackWalker(dwProcessId, hProcess) 
   {
   }
   virtual void OnOutput(LPCSTR szText) 
   { 
      printf(szText); 
      fprintf(sgLogFile, "%s",szText);
      fclose(sgLogFile);
      StackWalker::OnOutput(szText); 
   }
};

LONG Win32FaultHandler(struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *  ExInfo)
{
    MyStackWalker sw;   
    sw.ShowCallstack();
    return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}

void InstallFaultHandler()
{
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter((LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER) Win32FaultHandler);
}
```

But i get linker error now that symbols are not found,

```
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: int __thiscall StackWalker::ShowCallstack(void *,struct _CONTEXT const *,int (__stdcall*)(void *,unsigned __int64,void *,int,unsigned long *,void *),void *)" (?ShowCallstack@StackWalker@@QAEHPAXPBU_CONTEXT@@P6GH0_K0HPAK0@Z0@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall StackWalker::OnDbgHelpErr(char const *,int,unsigned __int64)(?OnDbgHelpErr@StackWalker@@MAEXPBDH_K@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall StackWalker::OnLoadModule(char const *,char const *,unsigned __int64,int,int,char const *,char const *,unsigned __int64)" (?OnLoadModule@StackWalker@@MAEXPBD0_KHH001@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall StackWalker::OnSymInit(char const *,int,char const *)" (?OnSymInit@StackWalker@@MAEXPBDH0@Z)
main.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall StackWalker::StackWalker(int,char const *,int,void *)" (??0StackWalker@@QAE@HPBDHPAX@Z)
release/Prog.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
Error executing link.exe.
```

I have modified the StackWalker.cpp file to adapt to the UNICODE support, replaced "_tcscat_s" with "wcscat".

can you see, what's going wrong here?

Comment: Keep in mind that your users are likely to call any unexpected action a "crash". That includes hangs, graphical corruption, and even faulty data. A crash log will only capture true crashes.

Comment: hello MSalters, thanks for your reply, yes i understand that, it would be okay to only have "true crashes", rest i can manage with the info provided by users in bug tracking system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For cross-platform application Breakpad is probably better solution. But easy way for Windows -is to set unhandled exception handler via SetUnhandledExceptionFilter and write minidumps (with configuration you need) with WriteMiniDumpEx in handler.

[example](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/james_research/MouseLight/src/classes/mdump.cpp)

Comment: hello again, i tried few solution based on SetUnHandledExceptionFilter, but they seems to be not helping much, Google breakpad seems very complicated in terms of getting the crash log(it asks to setup server and such things, basically poor documentation) anything simple and easy to use specifically with Qt+Windows would be really good. still looking for a good answer

Comment: Added link to example. Two things for you to check. First - do you have dbghelp.dll installed? It wasn't installed on old MS operating system so you have to distribute it with your application. Second - make sure that QT doesn't handles unhandled exception (or in such case manually case TopLevelFilter(0) in QT handler - you'll still get stack if not exception info.

Answer (score 6):

[Google Breakpad](http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/) is a cross-platform crash-report library that seems useful.

See also the [StackWalker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/StackWalker.aspx) for some windows-only code for getting a stack trace.

Also, installing an event filter by overriding `QCoreApplication::notify` and catch all exceptions (including asyncronous ones such as stack overflow and access violation on Windows) is a good idea.

Comment: i will try with Google breakpad first, let's hope for the best, other wise i will go for QCoreApplicaton::notify,... anyway thanks for your answer

Comment: hello again, i tried few solution based on SetUnHandledExceptionFilter, but they seems to be not helping much, Google breakpad seems very complicated in terms of getting the crash log(it asks to setup server and such things, basically poor documentation) anything simple and easy to use specifically with Qt+Windows would be really good. still looking for a good answer

Comment: @maxchirag: I've added a link to a solution for Windows that you should be able to integrate into your Qt application.

Comment: Hello Macke, thanks for your reply, i just looked at the stackwalker and it seems its more helpful in debuging but not getting crash log from customer end.

Comment: @maxchirag: Just replace `OutputDebugStringA(buffer);` with something like `fprintf(crashlog_fp, buffer)` and you should be able to store the trace to a file. I use our log system on our end, then pop up a message box that allows you to open the log file in notepad. That file can then easily be emailed or whatnot from the customer to you.

Comment: Hello Macke, i m trying that now, but i really doubt that the release version of binary will produce a call stack with source lines, i believe the log file will have some addresses and i need to map the addresses back to the source using some map file or so. but anyway, let me try this first and see what happens

Comment: Hello Macke, i have updated the question description and and has some linker error, could you please look into it and suggest something? thanks for your help

Comment: @maxchirag: Now you're turning it into a different question, i.e. how to use the StackWalker code, which means this turns into a support forum. Use a new question if you have specific issues such as that. However, it looks like you're not linking stackwalker.cpp into your exe at all, since all those are missing.

Comment: yes, i understand that, but i have linked the stackWalker.cpp, it seems the declaration of method is different then the call. (call without argument, defination with argument)

Comment: @Macke let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2310/discussion-between-maxchirag-and-macke)

Comment: @Macke why and how would I need to override `QCoreApplication::notify` for exception handling?

Comment: @philk: The idea is to catch exceptions that occur when the event is processed by the target object. Do that by wrapping QCoreApplication::notify() in YourApplication::notify() with try/catch.